# Java Module doesn't have `api`, and have to use `compile`?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

As stated in https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations, we now have `api` and `implementation`.

In Android Module i.e. `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`, we do have both.

However in a plain Java Module i.e. `apply plugin: 'java'` (Used by my Android App Module), I could only find `implementation`, but not `api`.

Hence in one of the dependent, I need to use `compile`, and can't use `api`.
Is `api` inaccessible at Java Module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
```

> **The key difference between the standard Java plugin and the Java Library plugin is that the latter introduces the concept of an API exposed to consumers**.
>
> **The plugin exposes two configurations that can be used to declare dependencies: `api` and `implementation`**.

More [info here.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html)